# Como fazer dois valores alternarem em uma variável sem repetir

Tags: php

tenho uma variável **$rt** que precisa alternar a cada refresh da página, porém sem repetir.

Se o valor da variável tiver como **0**, na próxima atualização da página o valor deve ser obrigatoriamente **1** e quando atualizar o valor da variável ser **0**.

Tenho este código que é meu pontapé inicial, mas não consigo pensar muita coisa sobre esta lógica.

```
if($rt==0)
{
$rt = 0;    
}else{
$rt = 1;        
}
```

Como podem me ajudar?

Tenho que alternar entre os valores 0 e 1

Comment: Ja considerou guardar o valor atual em uma base de dados? O valor vai varia a cada acesso de todos os usuário ou para cada usuário? Se for para cada usuário não vejo como fazer sem uma base de dados, ou cookie!

Comment: @CelsoMarigoJr para todos

Comment: @CelsoMarigoJr prefiro reorganizar este script para que os valores não se repitam

Comment: Pense que se o valor varia por sessão ele poderia ser definido em um cookie para ser verificado o anterior. Para setar o próximo. Acho que a pergunta esta muito vaga...  tente explicar o seu objetivo para que fique mais fácil sugerir uma solução.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pode fazer com [session](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_sessions.asp):

```
session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION['count'])) {
    $_SESSION['count'] = 0;
}
else {
    if($_SESSION['count'] == 0) {
        $_SESSION['count'] = 1;
    }
    else {
        $_SESSION['count'] = 0;
    }
}
echo $_SESSION['count']; // 0 ou 1
```

No entanto isto não lhe dá persistência, ao final de algum tempo a contagem já não está armazenada e recomeça. E tudo depende do utilizador, se este apagar os cookies ou, nem sequer os tiver ativos isto não resulta.

Pode também fazer com [cookies](http://php.net/manual/en/features.cookies.php), isto consegue dar-lhe mais persistência que session no entanto também, como disse em cima, depende do utilizador:

```
if(!isset($_COOKIE['count'])) {
    setcookie('count', 0, time()+99999); # time()+99999 é a data de expiração do cookie, quando deixa de estar ativo
}
else {
    if($_COOKIE['count'] == 0) {
        setcookie('count', 1, time()+99999);
    }
    else {
        setcookie('count', 0, time()+99999);
    }
}
echo (isset($_COOKIE['count'])) ? $_COOKIE['count'] : 0; // 0 ou 1
```

Nota que ambas as opções devem estar no topo da página, antes de qualquer output.

Se precisar mesmo de persistência opte por conectar-se a uma base de dados a armazene lá os dados que precisa

Comment: Tenho que alternar entre os valores 1 e 2

Comment: @GladisonNeuzaPerosini, editado

Comment: Erro na session:
Warning: session_start() [function.session-start]: Cannot send session cookie - headers already sent by (output started at /home/exibirimoveiscom/public_html/guaraparivirtual/index.php:1) in /home/exibirimoveiscom/public_html/guaraparivirtual/index.php on line 4

Comment: Isto que está aqui, ambas as opções devem estar no topo da  página sempre @GladisonNeuzaPerosini. Antes de tudo, logo na linha a seguir a `<?php`